# Software Engineering not appearing on My Communities

Tags: support, community, software-engineering

Since the name changed to Software Engineering, i am not able to see it on My Communities.

Are you guys experiencing the same issue? Or maybe i did something wrong?

I have to look it on More Stack Exchange Communities:

[image]

Looking forward to an answer, thanks in advance,

Comment: Is this in the top bar? I just went to Project Management and saw it under My Communities.

Comment: Yes, the issue appears on the Android app as well.  I have to scroll all the way to Software Engineering

Comment: Interesting. I don't see it on either the Android app or in the top bar. I did have some problems when the name was new, but they cleared up.

Comment: I just did some digging. It looks like the default list under "Your Communities" is your top 5 sites, ordered by reputation. You only have 101 reputation here on Software Engineering. It appears that alphabetical was the next sorting. If you're saying that it used to appear, I'm not sure why - it should have always been after Mathematics. If you edited the list to manually add it, maybe the name change bumped it away. If you click Edit next to your communities, can you add it? And if so, does it persist? I'd have to check out the Android app more.

Comment: You were right, maybe it was removed when they changed the name. Please post this to give you the answer. I also had to add it in the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the default list under "Your Communities" is your top 5 sites, ordered by reputation. You only have 101 reputation here on Software Engineering. It appears that alphabetical was the next sorting. If you're saying that it used to appear, I'm not sure why - it should have always been after Mathematics. If you edited the list to manually add it, maybe the name change bumped it away.